# Handlebars.js printing object doesn't work

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

this might be real simple but I've tried many examples and still couldn't make it working.
So I've got this code to check if the entry is written by the author and if so, I want to print it into template.

```
function printTitltes() {
    var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
    var author  = currentUser["username"];
    var allEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries"));
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#template").html());
    var authorEntry;
    if (!allEntries) {
        return
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i<allEntries.length; i++) {
            if (allEntries[i]["author"] === author) {
                authorEntry = allEntries[i];
                $("#titleArea").append(template(authorEntry));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my template is:

```
<script type='text/template' id='template'>
  <ul class="entries-list">
    {{#each auhorEntry}}
        <li data-id="{{ID}}">
          <span>  {{date}} </span>
          <a href=""> {{title}} </a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>    
</script>
```

When executed, all I got is an empty template. I've must have been sending a wrong object to the template but couldn't grasp how could I do it right. Anyone whould spot it for me please?

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template">`

Comment: Do you also have an explanation?